# How do I start two programs in a certain order startup using systemd?

Tags: boot, services, systemd

I am looking for guidance on the best way to achieve the following criteria using systemd.

1. I would like to start two services Program_A and Program_B at boot up time.
2. Program_B is dependent on Program_A so I would like to make sure Program_A is running before running Program_B
3. I would like them both to restart automatically if they crash or stop running.

Answer (score 0):

1. To have them start at boot, run systemctl enable Program_A and then repeat it for Program_B
2. In the service file for Program_B, within the [Unit] section add a line similar to
   *After=Program_A*.
3. To restart automatically, add the line *Restart=on-failure* within the [Service] section.

Hope this helps.
To

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Not sure but I am trying to add a new service file in   /etc/systemd/system  that has the following information in it.  From that file I am trying to call a script that starts the actual program.  Will that work? 
[Unit]
Description=my service

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/dev/Start.sh

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: I usually put the service file under /lib/systemd/system/, and then run systemctl enable <service filename>. Is your Start.sh script not getting executed? Did you run systemctl daemon-reload after adding the service file?